# Code to fix filter by Person in a DVWP in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

Does anyone have the code to fix a DVWP where the column title filter shows the html rather than the person's name?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the XSLT of the web part to fix this.

Find the statement that says:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@YourColumnName">
```

And replace it with:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@YourColumnName">
```

From [How to display HTML in the Dataview & Content Query Webpart (DVWP CQWP)](http://www.petestilgoe.com/2010/07/displaying-html-in-the-dataview-webpart-dvwp/)